# XElement - how do I get descendants of an element into a string

Tags: c#

I'm using an XElement object in`.Net 3.5 Framework` to load the following xml fragment.

Example XML:

```
<xmlfragment>
  <list id="1" value="one" />
  <list id="2" value="two" />
  <other stuff="here" />
  <more things="as well"></more>
</xmlfragment>
```

How can I get the descendants of xmlfragment into a string? In other words, put everything in a string except the xmlfragment tag.

The following works, but was wondering if this was the most concise way.

```
string results = String.Join(" ", xmlfragment.DescendantNodes().Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: Well you don't need to create an array, and `ToString()` would be called automatically, so `String.Join(" ", xmlfragment.DescendantNodes())` should work...

Comment: An honor!!  : )  When I try that it says "cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode> to string[]

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? String.Join has accepted `IEnumerable<T>` for *years*... If you're using a very old version of .NET (e.g. .NET 3.5) you should *really* say so in the question.

Comment: Ahh, that's prolly it, I'm using .Net 3.5 : ( Sorry about that.

Comment: Right, in that case if *at all* possible, I'd move to something that was released less than 9.5 years ago...

Comment: So would the code I have in my post be the best way to do it then?

Comment: If it works, then yes, it may well be the simplest solution in .NET 3.5. Although I suspect it *doesn't* work properly, in that any more-nested nodes would be listed multiple times. (Try putting another element in one of your direct children...)

Comment: You're right! So what can I do?!

Comment: Use `Nodes()` instead of `DescendantNodes()`?

Comment: Yay, that worked! thanks so much. And if you care to share some insight I gladly welcome it because it seemed DescendantNodes would make sense.

Comment: Hey, how about `var result = string.Join(" ", xElement.Elements().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());`

Comment: That works too, technically, Jon's answer worked first but his is not listed in answers below. I'll give him some time to add it. Otherwise, I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks everyone for the fast feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using .NET 3.5, there are no particularly easier ways of simplifying this - although if you find yourself needing it frequently, you could always write your own static methods to emulate the new overloads of `string.Join`. It's possible that you could use a method group conversion instead of the lambda expression in the `Select` call, but if you're *also* using an old C# compiler, that may well cause problems too. (The exact rules around type inference and method group conversions have changed over time.)

The current code will fail when there are nested elements, however. It looks like you only want the direct child nodes:

```
string results = string.Join(" ", xmlFragment.Nodes().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 3.5, simply do

```
var result = string.Join(" ", xElement.Elements().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

So, even if there is multiple level hierarchy, this would not fail.

Comment: My apologies, I failed to indicate that I'm using the .Net 3.5 Framework.

Comment: Why are you skipping a node when the original working code doesn't? Ditto your use of `string.Empty` instead of a space...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Coz OP said `put everything in a string except the xmlfragment tag.`. The skipped line contains whole xml starting from xmlfragement. Hence removed it.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: That would be the case if you'd used `DescendantsAndSelf()`... and now you've decided to use `Environment.NewLine` instead of space. The OP has said their current code works for them, so I'd expect an answer to give the same output - your answer doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet: tried and tested updated answer with adding another element in `more` element.

Comment: It won't give any text nodes directly within `xmlfragment` though

Comment: @JonSkeet: Its giving me. `<list id="1" value="one" /> <list id="2" value="two" /> <other stuff="here" /> <more things="as well"></more>` and I am creating XElement like this `var xElement = XElement.Parse(str);`

Comment: Unless you've tested adding a text node directly beneath `xmlfragment`, you've missed the point of my comment.

Comment: I think that would be overkill and an assumption. Moreover, OP has posted his xml in the code. Anything beyond that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to cut the first line and the last one.

```
string originalString = xdoc.ToString();
int startIndex = originalString.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine.Length;

var stringWithoutParent = originalString.Substring(startIndex,
    originalString.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine) - startIndex);
```

If you want the elements to be space separated (instead of line and indentation) then add also:

```
.Replace(" ", "")
.Replace(Environment.NewLine," ");
```

If you are not manipulating the xml, and it is as you've shown line separted, then there's no need to use `XElement` at all.

Comment: XElement is a given in this particular case.